# Why are undefined and function declarations/expressions not considered literals?

Tags: javascript

This [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) lists literals. I presume it's exhaustive (displays all possible literals).

It lists: string literals (`"str"|'str'`); template literals; numeric literals i.e. `5`; boolean literals i.e. `true`; `null` literal; array literals (`[1, 2]`) and object literals (`{num: 5}`).

Why are `undefined` and function declaration/expressions not literals?

Edit: I now know that literals are in contrast to variables and can sometimes be used to assign variables which is why function expressions and not function declarations are considered [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)).

Comment: null is not boolean literal

Comment: `undefined` is a variable in global scope referring to a primitive value, *not* a literal: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: @jonrsharpe is the primitive value it refers to not `undefined`?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined

Comment: @jonrshape ok, so my question is what is the purpose of the term literal? Why wouldn't undefined and function declarations/expressions be considered literals?

Comment: At first we need to define ["_literal_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)). According to the linked Wiki article, anonymous function expressions are also literals.

Comment: @Teemu that's good to know! I wonder why it wasn't mentioned in the spec I hyperlinked. I also wonder if the `undefined` primitive value is a literal as well.

Comment: @tonitone117 It isn't. `undefined` is a property in the global scope that holds the primitive value `undefined`. It's as much of a literal as `alert` is. In the old days you could even assign a different value to `undefined`. You can't do that to literals.

Comment: @Ivar I just meant if the `undefined` *primitive* was a literal

Comment: @tonitone117 There is the `undefined` global property and the `undefined` primitive value. The primitive value has no literal. It is automatically assigned to variables that don't have any value explicitly set, as well arguments that aren't passed etc. The value is as well assigned to the global property `undefined`, but that does not make this a literal. Like I mentioned, the `undefined` that you use in your code is no different from the global property `alert` that you can use. Neither of them are literals.This is unlike things like `true`.

Comment: If you use `undefined = '';` in strict mode you get an error "_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'undefined' of object '#<Window>'_". If you declare it as a new variable in the global scope you'll get "_Identifier 'undefined' has already been declared_". If you declare it in a function, you will actually create a new variable named `undefined` which you can use within that scope. If you assign something to `true` it will always result in a syntax error. (Either "_Invalid left-hand side in assignment_" or "_Unexpected token 'true'_".)

Comment: @Ivar Thanks for that what I got from it is every-time the coder types `undefined` they are referencing the global property `undefined` which returns the primitive value `undefined`. And things like uninitialised variables and parameters with no argument return the primitive `undefined`. In any case, I'm still left wondering why the primitive value is not considered a literal?

Comment: And also, what is the purpose of the word 'literal'. Wikipedia told me literals are often used in contrast to variables.