# Why is undefined not a literal and what is the purpose of the term literal?

Tags: javascript

I thought this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar) was an exhaustive list of literals. I was then told function expressions were also literals (something the MDN page didn't mention).

My current understanding of all the literals in JavaScript is:

string literals ("str"|'str'); template literals; numeric literals i.e. 5; boolean literals i.e. true; null literal; array literals ([1, 2]) and object literals ({num: 5}).

Same to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63154617/why-are-undefined-and-function-declarations-expressions-not-considered-literals) I asked, I'm wondering why:

1. The primitive value `undefined` is not a literal.
2. The purpose of the term 'literal'. Why have we created this term?

i) This [article](https://www.quora.com/What-are-literals-in-programming) says: a literal is

> something that has a fixed value that was set by a programmer during the creation of the code.

ii) And this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)) contrasts literals with variables saying variables are often initialised by literals.

I'm just left wondering why the primitive `undefined` is not a literal since i) it seems like a fixed value and ii) it can initialise a variable

Comment: ["In computer science, a literal is a notation for representing a fixed value in source code."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_\(computer_programming\)). Note, that due to legacy reasons, `undefined` is not a keyword, but a property of the global object. Strictly speaking, when writing `let v = undefined;`, you could be assigning something else than the value `undefined`. However, i see that as very nit-picky, and would consider `undefined` as a literal, as e.g. shadowing `undefined` is a really absurd case. Strictly speaking, that problem exists though.

Comment: However, this has already been mentioned in your linked previous question, so i don't really understand, what aspect you are still confused about.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I don't understand what it being a global property has to do with anything. The property undefined returns the primitive value, `undefined` and it's this primitive value I'm concerned about

Comment: `"use strict"; function f(undefined) { console.log(undefined); }; f("totally undefined");`

Comment: What's that meant to be showing me?

Comment: That `undefined` is not a primitive value, or even any predefined value, in that case. It's a legacy problem of javascript.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167317/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-parameter-named-undefined-in-a-javascript-function and related questions about how `undefined` works (and worked before)

Comment: A literal must either take a syntactic form other than an identifier, or it must be a keyword (reserved word that's not allowed for usage as an identifier). `undefined` is not a reserved word for mostly historical accident, and that causes it to not be counted as a literal. Using `undefined` in your code is a variable reference.

Comment: As a side note, i wonder, whether one could start a flamewar, about whether `void 0` is a literal or not. I mean, strictly speaking, it's an operator first, but will any engine actually treat it differently than just immediately inserting the value `undefined`?

Comment: @ASDFGerte It's clearly a unary expression with a literal as the operand. Yes, it will probably be constant-folded, but that definitely doesn't make it a literal. Same for e.g. `5+1`.